# Is there a one-to-one mapping between every planar graph and a Delaunay tessellation of the plane?

Tags: graph-theory, tessellations

For every planar undirected finite graph is there a corresponding Delaunay tessellation of the plane, and vice versa?  Has this been proven?

Comment: Possibly useful:  “Recognizing Dirichlet Tessellations” (with Peter Ash), 
Geometreia  Dedicata , 19, 1985, 175-206. http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/dirichlet/RecognizingDTs.pdf

Comment: Perhaps we need to impose some conditions on the mapping that we are seeking? Otherwise it seems like such mapping exists since both sets are countable.